# How can I switch to Fetch instead of XHR when using angular 6 with HttpClient

Tags: javascript, angular, fetch

I have been into angular 4 and 6 for some time now,and I have been making Services to use HTTP calls in it.
something like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class ApiService
{
    private apiUrl:string;
    constructor(
        private  httpClient:  HttpClient,
        private config: ConfigService,
        private cookieService: CookieService
    )
    {
        this.apiUrl = this.config.get("apiEndpoint");
    }
    private headers() :any
    {
        let headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers = headers.set('Accept', 'application/json');
        headers = headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer '+this.cookieService.get("token"));
        return headers;
    }
    public get(url): any
    {
        return this.httpClient.get(`${this.apiUrl}${url}`, this.headers());
    }
    public post(url, data = {}): any
    {
        return this.httpClient.post(`${this.apiUrl}${url}`, data, this.headers());
    }
    public put(url, data = {}): any
    {
        return this.httpClient.put(`${this.apiUrl}${url}`, data, this.headers());
    }
    public patch(url, data = {}): any
    {
        return this.httpClient.patch(`${this.apiUrl}${url}`, data, this.headers());
    }
    public delete(url, data = {}): any
    {
        return this.httpClient.delete(`${this.apiUrl}${url}`, this.headers());
    }
}
```

Which by default using XHR how can I swith to fetch ?

Comment: Why? You're supposed to use `HttpClient` and not care for its inner implementation. It could change to `fetch` one day when it's ready.

Comment: Adding to @LazarLjubenović  - if you have to show file upload progress you are out of luck with fetch (as of 2020). Also supporting IE11 needs fetch polyfill.

Comment: Also, When you are using ServiceWorker XHR is nos available, but fetch is, currently developing Chrome extension with Angular

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, there's **no reason** to do so. What `HttpClient` uses under the hood is considered an **implementation detail** and it shouldn't concern you if it's using XHR or `fetch` under the hood. It's currently using XHR, but that could change any time and you'd not even know it.

---

Still, to answer your question: if you *really* want to use `fetch` in your code, then the easiest thing is to just... use `fetch`? Do not use `HttpClient` at all.

```
public get(url): any
{
    return fetch(`${this.apiUrl}${url}`, this.headers());
}
```

The alternative is to re-implement whole `HttpClient` (yikes!) and then provide your custom `fetch`-like implementation (eg. `FetchHttpClient`).

```
providers: [
  { provide: HttpClient, useClass: FetchHttpClient }
]
```

Comment: When you are using ServiceWorker XHR is nos available, but fetch is, so, that's a reason.

Comment: This is very bad suggestion. Doing so you unplug the HttpBackend and all you request don't go through the interceptors.

Comment: HttpClient was using only XHR under the hood when the answer was written, and the question had no Web Worker context provided in the comments. Of course you're losing everything that comes with HttpClient if you don't use HttpClient.

Answer (score 1):

Since Angular 16.1 angular provides a `HttpBackend` with a `fetch` implementation.

Just use `withFetch()` within `provideHttpClient()`

Comment: The Fetch Api does not support progress file uploads. Is there a possibility to force use xhr for upload requests, but for the rest requests - use the Fetch API ? I just do not know, how to force use XHR, when I have configured `provideHttpClient(withFetch())`

Comment: This is a known limitation and no it's not possible.